# Send variable to next page without overwriting

Tags: mysql, session, post, while-loop, href

I want to pass $ids variable retrieved from db from page1 to page2 with session method but the code doesn't work or overwrites the variable.

page1

```
<?php 

$queryString = "WHERE id='$id'";
$sqls = mysql_query("SELECT ids FROM markers $queryString"); 
$i=0;

while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sqls)) { 

$_SESSION['ids'][$i]=$row['ids']; 
echo $_SESSION['ids'][$i];
echo '<a href="page2.php">Modify</a><br />';   
$i++;
}
//echo $_SESSION['ids'];
?>
```

page2

```
<?php 
session_start(); 
include_once "scripts/connect_to_mysql.php"; 
$ids= $_SESSION['ids'].[$i]; 
//echo $ids;
?>
```

Thanks a lot for help.

Comment: without ].[ in the second page

Answer (score 0):

you must do also `session_start();` in page1 to work with sesion variables.

your code should work like that:

```
 while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sqls)) { 
    $arrays[]=$row['ids'];
    $_SESSION['ids']= $arrays[]; 
    echo $_SESSION['ids'][0];
    echo $_SESSION['ids'][1];
    .......
   echo '<a href="page2.php">Modify</a><br />';   
   }
```

page2

```
<?php 
session_start(); 
include_once "scripts/connect_to_mysql.php"; 
 $ids= $_SESSION['ids']; 
echo $ids[0];
echo $ids[1];......
?>
```

Comment: yes it's true. I forgot it here but there is in my code. Other advice?

Comment: It shows nothing. I think it's the correct way but I did the same thing with $i counter.

Comment: did your query have results ? when you defining $id ?

Comment: Yes I have results and $id is another variable and it works fine. The only problem is to rename $_SESSION['ids'] with different name for each iteration and than retrieve it in the second page. I can not use form POST/GET method because I have to work with $ids. Session method is the unique choise.

Comment: you have no result in page1 this `echo $_SESSION['ids'][0];` ??

Comment: how is this ids in your table ? is it array or what ? give an example . echo this and see what it gives in page1 `$row['ids']`

Comment: page1<?php 
  session_start();  
   
 $queryString = "WHERE id='$id'";

$sqls = mysql_query("SELECT ids FROM markers $queryString"); 
 $i=0;
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sqls)) { 
 
  
   $_SESSION[$i]=$row['ids'];
  echo $_SESSION[$i];
  echo '<a href="page2.php">Modify</a><br />';

 $i++;
   }


 ?>

Comment: page2<?php 
session_start(); 

include_once "scripts/connect_to_mysql.php";
$id= $_SESSION['id'];
$ids= $_SESSION[$i]; 
echo $ids;
echo $id;
if ($_POST['parse_var'] == "title"){

        $title = $_POST['title'];
  
        $sqlUpdate = mysql_query("UPDATE markers SET title='$title' WHERE ids='$ids'");
  

}


?>

Comment: it's a variable, a random number. In fact its value has updated each time in the while loop and it assumes the last value in the end, overwritten. This is the problem.

Comment: try just echo this `echo $ids;` in page2 and tell what it gives.